# Unrecognized selector error on swipe left gesture swift

Tags: swift, unrecognized-selector

I am attempting to create a simple swift left segue to the next view controller, however I am getting an unrecognized selector error.  This the code failing:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //below creates the instances for swiping to change screens
        //only added right here because it's the main screen

          var swipeLeft : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipe:"))
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        func swipe(Sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!) {
            print("swiped left")
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnDeck") as! OnDeck
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
2017-06-07 19:07:00.990 Test[65722:3911717] -[Test.GameView swipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc2d310f700
2017-06-07 19:07:01.000 Test[65722:3911717] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test.GameView swipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc2d310f700'
```

Comment: Your swipe function needs to be at the top level of the class (a sibling of `viewDidLoad`).  It can't be nested inside of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: thank you, just brought it out and it functions perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

In your case for **Swift 3** the selector should look like this:

```
#selector(swipe(Sender:))
```

You can use the `#selector` notation to get compile-time checks.

For **Swift 2** the selector would be:

```
#selector(swipe(_:))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try it like that :

```
let swiftLeft : UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipe(Sender:)))
swiftLeft.direction = .left
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swiftLeft)

func swipe(Sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!) {
     print("swiped left")
        
}
```

If you are working on Swift 2, you need to add the selector like that

## selector(self.swipe(_:))

Comment: This is giving me an error: `the class has no member swipe(Sender:)`

Comment: ah, this is still on swift 2, that would be the confusion